# Convert hexadecimal numbers to decimal numbers

Tags: c, file, hex, decimal, converters

I have a text file with one line with numbers separated by space as in the following example:

```
1 -2 3.1 0xf 0xcc
```

After parsing the file with a C program,the results should be saved in a vector and its internal structure should be:

```
V[0]=1
V[1]=-2
V[2]=3.1
V[3]=15
V[4]=204
```

Basically i need to convert the numbers that start with 0x into decimal numbers.

I have tried storing all elements in a char vector and then transform them in numbers but without much succes.

Any help with a piece of code in C will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: `strtol` with a base of `0` will take care of everything except `3.1`. For `3.1` you'll need to check the `endptr` to realize that it's not an integer, and then use `strtod` to convert to a `double`.

Comment: Thanks for information.Can you post an actual code example based on my example?Thanks in regards anyway.

Comment: Is there some order for the input? Or can the different kinds of numbers appear in any order and you need to find which type each number is?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) function for integer types. You can use `endptr` to iterate through the string. For `double` you can use [atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) function, but you have to check firstly if the string contains a dot.

EDIT: As [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) mentioned [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) is a better solution for `double`.

Assuming that you have the string in an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char numbers_str[] = "1 -2 3.1 0xf 0xcc";
    int ints[10];
    double doubles[10];
    int ints_idx = 0, doubles_idx = 0;

    const char delims[] = " ";
    char *it = strtok(numbers_str, delims);
    while(it != NULL)
    {
        char *dot_it = strchr(it, '.');
        // When a dot is found then a double number is found
        if(dot_it)
            doubles[doubles_idx++] = strtod(it, NULL);
        // When a dot is not found then we've got an integer
        else
            ints[ints_idx++] = strtol(it, NULL, 0);
        it = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }

    printf("Integers found: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < ints_idx; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", ints[i]);

    printf("Double numbers found: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < doubles_idx; ++i)
        printf("%f\n", doubles[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
Can you please post an algorithm representation of what you propose or a piece of code based on my example to make it clearer for me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here you have a simple solution. It does not take into account overflow of `doubles` and `ints` arrays but you can simply check if the overflow could occur and use `realloc` on dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a [look at](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) `sscanf`. Here's a bare-bones program. I am sure you can pick up from here:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *hex = "0xF";
    int i= 0;
    sscanf(hex, "%x", &i);
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle reading the values from the line is to work your way down the line with `strtod`. `strtod` takes two pointers as parameters. The first points to the beginning point to search for digits (or leading `+/-`) in order to convert the string representation of the number to a numeric value (all leading whitespace is skipped). The second pointer-to-pointer (`endptr`) will be set to the next character following the last character used in the conversion. You start your search for the next number to convert from there (e.g. set `p = ep;` and repeat the process).

You can consult the man page for further details, but to validate a successful conversion, you check that the pointer is not equal to the end-pointer (meaning digits were converted) and you check to make sure `errno` was not set. If there were no digits converted (meaning you had an invalid character), you simply want to scan forward in the line manually until your next `+/-` or `0-9` is found (or you hit the *nul-terminating* character).

You want to protect your array bounds and limit the number of values you try and store in your vector array by keeping a simple counter and exiting the loop when your array is full.

Here is a short example (NAN and INF checking omitted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define VECSZ 5   /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int i, n = 0;
    double v[VECSZ] = {0.0};
    char buf[BUFSIZ] = "";
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (n < VECSZ && fgets (buf, BUFSIZ, fp)) { /* read each line */
        char *p = buf, *ep;     /* pointer, end-pointer for strtod  */
        while (n < VECSZ) {     /* convert vales in buf until VECSZ */
            double tmp = strtod (p, &ep);
            if (p != ep) {                  /* digits converted  */
                if (!errno)                 /* validate no error */
                    v[n++] = tmp;           /* add to vector  */
                p = ep;                     /* update pointer */
            }
            else {  /* no digits converted */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: no digits converted.\n");
                /* scan forward to next valid '+,-,0-9' */
                while (*p && *p != '-' && *p != '+' && (*p < '1' || '9' < *p))
                    p++;
                if (*p)         /* numbers remain in line */
                    continue;
                break;          /* otherwise get next line */
            }
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("v[%d]=% g\n", i, v[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/strtod_vect.txt
1 -2 3.1 0xf 0xcc
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtod_vect dat/strtod_vect.txt
v[0]= 1
v[1]=-2
v[2]= 3.1
v[3]= 15
v[4]= 204
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. You can check [strtod(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) for further details and error checking that can be done.